# Does autotrader.com (vehicle marketplace) offer an API for posting vehicles?

Tags: api, edi

Does anybody know if autotrader.com offers an API or something that would help with mass postings of vehicles?

Or does anybody have any idea of what to use to create something like this?  I was thinking of maybe a mouse location and click over a browser window type of thing.

Comment: Probably best to speak to them - they seem to have a dedicated website for dealers at: https://dealers.autotrader.com/dc/portal/index.jsf -- they probably allow for EDI or some form of web service for bulk posting

Comment: I imagine you'd get the best help by just emailing them and asking!

Answer (score 7):

AutoTrader provides a bulk upload feature through a file feed process. The file runs through a set of processes to associate it with the proper listing tier (Premium, Feature or Standard) and in addition normalizes the information across vehicle make and models. This process runs several times daily and is being migrated to a near real-time solution for quicker add or updates.

Answer (score 0):

I can find no documentation on it but I've come across this link which seems to provide a `json` response.

`https://www.autotrader.com/rest/searchresults/sunset/base`